# PDO in CakePHP and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo, mysqli

I get this error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered 
queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code 
is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the 
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

How do you set this PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-use-buffered-query :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('select * from foo',
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));
```

(But if this is really a good solution to your problem is another question....)

Comment: thanks, i found that the cakephp code already set that, but somehow in cakephp i can't run a stored procedure (cakephp 2.1)

Comment: How is this $db (new connection) initiate by using 'default' databse configuration in Config file?